# Python self generating variables?

Tags: python, regex, generics, coding-style, styles

I'm writing a program which reads a big .txt file with lotto numbers. This means that there are always 7 int in one array. (6 from 49 and last one is supernumber).

For example: [[1, 11, 25, 37, 39, 47, 0],[3, 13, 15, 18, 37, 46, 0], ...]

I've got every Month in this .txt which means that it is like

```
January:
[1, 11, 25, 37, 39, 47, 0]
[3, 13, 15, 18, 37, 46, 2]
[3,  6,  9, 12, 37, 46, 6]

February:
[3, 13, 15, 18, 37, 46, 0]
[1, 23, 17, 18, 37, 46, 8]

...
```

and so on

How can I generate an array which just reads the numbers of month?

I have a solution but it is very bad coding style:

```
jan_tipps = []
feb_tipps = []
mar_tipps = []

#variable which month has to be checked
jan = False
feb = False
mar = False

for line in wholefile:
    if line == '\n':
        pass
    elif line == 'January:\n':
        jan = True
    elif line == 'February:\n':
        jan = False
        feb = True
    elif line == 'March:\n':
        feb = False
        mar = True
    elif jan == True:
        jan_tipps.append(line.split())

    elif feb == True:
        feb_tipps.append(line.split())
        
    elif mar == True:
        mar_tipps.append(line.split())
```

I guess I need something like generics or self generating variables. I don't know what I have to search for in the internet.

Comment: You need a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Klaus D. comments, you need a dictionary. But I suspect that is not enough of a hint. Here is a more extended answer.

One issue: Your code doesn't agree with the input data you present. Your code splits the numbers on spaces, but the input data has square brackets and commas instead. This code works with the input you present.

```
# Parser states:
# 0: waiting for a month name
# 1: expecting numbers in the format [1, 11, 25, 37, 39, 47, 0]

from collections import defaultdict

state = 0
tipps = defaultdict(list)
monthname = None

with open("numbers.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if state == 0:
            if line.strip().endswith(":"):
                monthname = line.split(":")[0]
                state = 1
            continue
        if state == 1:
            if line.startswith("["):
                line = line.strip().strip("[]")
                numbers = line.split(",")
                tipps[monthname].append([int(n) for n in numbers])
            elif not line.strip():
                state = 0
            else:
                print (f"Unexpected data, parser stuck: {line}")
                break

for k,v in tipps.items():
    print (f"{k}: {v}")
```

Output is:

```
January: [[1, 11, 25, 37, 39, 47, 0], [3, 13, 15, 18, 37, 46, 2], [3, 6, 9, 12, 37, 46, 6]]
February: [[3, 13, 15, 18, 37, 46, 0], [1, 23, 17, 18, 37, 46, 8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression:

```
import re

lotto = """
January:
[1, 11, 25, 37, 39, 47, 0]
[3, 13, 15, 18, 37, 46, 2]
[3,  6,  9, 12, 37, 46, 6]

February:
[3, 13, 15, 18, 37, 46, 0]
[1, 23, 17, 18, 37, 46, 8]
"""

def getMonthlyNumbers(month=None):
    rx = re.compile(r'''
        ^{}:[\n\r]
        (?P<numbers>(?:^\[.+\][\n\r]?)+)'''.format(month), re.M | re.X)

    for match in rx.finditer(lotto):
        # print it or do sth. else here
        print(match.group('numbers'))

getMonthlyNumbers('January')
getMonthlyNumbers('February')
```

---

Or, **for all months**, using a dict comprehension:

```
rx = re.compile(r'^(?P<month>\w+):[\n\r](?P<numbers>(?:^\[.+\][\n\r]?)+)', re.MULTILINE)

result = {m.group('month'): m.group('numbers') for m in rx.finditer(lotto)}

print(result)
```

Which yields

```
{'January': '[1, 11, 25, 37, 39, 47, 0]\n[3, 13, 15, 18, 37, 46, 2]\n[3,  6,  9, 12, 37, 46, 6]\n', 'February': '[3, 13, 15, 18, 37, 46, 0]\n[1, 23, 17, 18, 37, 46, 8]\n'}
```

The idea here is to look for month names at the start of a line and capture any `[...]` pair afterwards. See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/XJW9Ba/1).

---

Probably, you want to have each row as a list on its own (not as a string), hence you could go for:

```
import re
from ast import literal_eval

lotto = """
January:
[1, 11, 25, 37, 39, 47, 0]
[3, 13, 15, 18, 37, 46, 2]
[3,  6,  9, 12, 37, 46, 6]

February:
[3, 13, 15, 18, 37, 46, 0]
[1, 23, 17, 18, 37, 46, 8]
"""

rx = re.compile(r'^(?P<month>\w+):[\n\r](?P<numbers>(?:^\[.+\][\n\r]?)+)', re.MULTILINE)

result = {m.group('month'): 
    [literal_eval(numbers) 
    for numbers in m.group('numbers').split("\n") if numbers] 
    for m in rx.finditer(lotto)}

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create dictionary of months with month name as key and array of array of what you want as value

```
month = {
    m: [] 
    for m in ['January', 'February']
}
with open('file.txt') as file:
    latest = None
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == '':  # striped empty line
            continue
        if line in month:
            latest = line
        else:
            month[latest].append(line.split())  # actually if line="[1, 2]" then better to use eval instaed of split(', ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to extract the month names, [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to parse the lists of numbers for each month, and a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to store them without needing to check if a month exists before appending a list to it:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import ast
import re

with open('file.txt') as file:
    months = defaultdict(list)
    month = None
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        m = re.match('([A-Z][a-z]+):', line)
        if m is not None:
            month = m.group(1)
        elif line.startswith('['):
            months[month].append(ast.literal_eval(line))
    for month, numbers in months.iteritems():
        print '{}: {}'.format(month, numbers)
```

Output:

```
January: [[1, 11, 25, 37, 39, 47, 0], [3, 13, 15, 18, 37, 46, 2], [3, 6, 9, 12, 37, 46, 6]]
February: [[3, 13, 15, 18, 37, 46, 0], [1, 23, 17, 18, 37, 46, 8]]
```